# No Duplicates Except Null/ Zero Length String in a table

Tags: ms-access

Is it possible to have a text field in a table, that does not allow duplicates, but accepts null? I'm using a form to enter the info and the info that goes into this column are supposed to be unique, but not every record will have one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of MS Access 2007 you can specify an UNIQUE-Constraint and allow NULL-Values.
You can try it by yourself or you can read it implicitly from http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/constraint-clause-HA001231437.aspx?CTT=1

Comment: Sorry, im extremely inexperienced with access. I have no idea what I'm suppose to do with that. :( It's not a primary key that is going to be null. Its just a regular field in a table.

Comment: So did I understood your question. If you're creating your table with the visual tools from Access you can select an unique index for a field. NULL values are allowed by default. Build such a table with say three columns, one of them with an unique index and allowing NULL values. Fill the table either in datagrid view or with INSERT statements.

Comment: Would I change these in opening the table > design view > indexes, and add the column? Selecting the Unique box, and setting it so that zero length strings are allowed?

Comment: zero length strings are something different than `NULL` values. I don't have an english version, so I translate the description to "input required". If nothing's changed it should be the property above "zero length strings".